# Does Avro support required fields?

Tags: avro

i.e. is it possible to make field required similar to ProtoBuf:

message SearchRequest { 
  **required** string query = 1; 
}

Answer (score 25, accepted):

All fields are required in Avro by default.  As is [mentioned](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedjava.html) in the official documentation, if you want to make something optional, you have to make it nullable by unioning its type with `null`, like this

```js
{ "namespace": "example.avro",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "User",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "favorite_number",  "type": ["int", "null"]},
    {"name": "favorite_color", "type": ["string", "null"]}
  ]
}
```

In this example, `name` is required, `favorite_number` and `favorite_color` are optional.  I recommend spending some more time with the documentation.

Comment: it works as long as both the fields favorite_number and favorite_color have the value 'null' but serialisation fail if I put a int or a string respectively. See my question below where I demonstrate it...